# GIT 2 or more merge conflicts in a single file - how p4merge handles?

Tags: git, conflict, git-merge, p4merge, merge-conflict-resolution

1. GIT p4merge - 2 or more conflict in same file

I have integrated p4merge with GIT and i came across this situation once.

I have a file with merge conflicts. The file say foo.c has merge conflicts in 3 different lines of code (the first line with conflict, some lines in the middle with conflicts).

When i resolved the first lines of conflict (not other lines of conflict) and saved (using save button on p4merge) i guess it adds the foo.c to index, and when i commit, git allows me to commit without giving me an error or warning to resolve the other conflicting lines in the same file.

Is this an issue with GIT or p4merge? i think GIT should warn or error out that there are other conflicting lines that file. but it just commits.

---

1. Merge specific file in GIT

The other question i have is is there a command so that i can send a developer to merge a certain file? When i run git mergetool it opens all merge conflict one by one, instead is there a way like clearcase where i can say merge this selected file?

Answer (score 4):

1. My guess: when you save file in p4merge, it happilly return with code 0, file is changed, and git assumes that conflicts were resolved. There is a config parameter `mergetool.<tool>.trustExitCode` (`mergetool.p4merge.trustExitCode` in your case), which can be set to false, so git will always ask you if merge was successfull after running `git mergetool` (which can be quite annoying). You also might be able to write a wrapper for `p4merge` which will check presence of conflict markers after running `p4mege`, or `pre-commit` hook, which rejects commits containing files containing such markers, though I've never done something like that.
2. Yes, you can run `git mergetool <file>` to resolve specified file. Learn more [here](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mergetool.html).