# Git with P4 merge is having issues

Tags: git, merge

We have integrated Git with Perforce merge.  We invoked the p4merge and it shows 5 conflicts. I resolved only one conflict and saved the merge. When I try to re-invoke the p4merge using gitmerge tool, it says "no merge required." We are not able to reinvoke the mergetool even though the merge is not complete.

Kindly advise.

Comment: Did you perhaps prematurely tell git the other conflicts were resolved, by running `git add <file-with-conflict>`? I could see that being really easy to accidentally do if there were multiple conflicts in one file and you only resolved one...

Comment: Perhaps this question has your answer? [git: two or more merge conflicts in a single file with p4merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067202/git-2-or-more-merge-conflicts-in-a-single-file-how-p4merge-handles)

Answer (score 0):

As [Jefromi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119963/jefromi) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068963/git-with-p4-merge-is-having-issues/12909330#comment4372896_4068963), the question "[GIT 2 or more merge conflicts in a single file - how `p4merge` handles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067202/git-2-or-more-merge-conflicts-in-a-single-file-how-p4merge-handles)" points to a possible cause (status 0 even if conflicts exist)

Wrappers can help debug the situation ([see some in this gist](https://gist.github.com/2588979)).
Checking for conflict maker can help you return a non-0 status, [like in this script](http://ulf.zeitform.de/en/documents/git-ediff.html) (for emacs, but you can adapt it for other tool)

```
# check modified file
if [ ! $(egrep -c '^(<<<<<<<|=======|>>>>>>>|####### Ancestor)' ${_MERGED}) = 0 ]; then
  _MERGEDSAVE=$(${_MKTEMP} --tmpdir `${_BASENAME} ${_MERGED}`.XXXXXXXXXX)
  ${_CP} ${_MERGED} ${_MERGEDSAVE}
  echo 1>&2 "Oops! Conflict markers detected in $_MERGED."
  echo 1>&2 "Saved your changes to ${_MERGEDSAVE}"
  echo 1>&2 "Exiting with code 1."
  exit 1
fi
```